# Injection of a mock object into an object to be tested declared as a field in the test does not work using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class and I am injecting a proxy into my service.

```
Service service
{
    private ServiceProxy proxy;
    public Service(ServiceProxy proxy)
    {
        this.proxy = proxy; 
    }
}
```

The test for it is:

```
ServiceTest
{
    @Mock
    ServiceProxy mockProxy;
    Service service = new Service(mockProxy);
}
```

If I initialize my class like this I always get a `NPE` when I want to use the service object. Why does `Mockito` do this? What is an easy way around this instead of declaring it in each and every test?

Comment: Can you include the stack of your NPE?  if you want to recreate this frequently, how about a method in a test utility class?

Comment: Are you using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, or are you using `initMocks`, to create your mock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provided you are using Mockito version 1.9.0 or later, the best way to achieve what you want is like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ServiceProxy proxy;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(service);
        assertNotNull(proxy);
    }
}
```

First thing is the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` declaration which will cause @Mock and @InjectMocks annotation to work automatically without any explicit initialization. The second thing is that starting with Mockito 1.9.0 @InjectMocks annotation can use the *Constructor injection* mechanism which is the best option for your *Service* class.

Other options for @InjectMocks are *Setter injection* and *Field injection* (see [docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/index.html) BTW) but you'd need a no argument constructor to use them.

So summarizing - your code cannot work because:

- you are not using the MockitoJUnitRunner nor MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) so @Mock annotation takes no effect
- even if above were satisfied your example would fail because *mockProxy* would be initialized **after** the test is constructed and your *service* is tried to be initialized during the test class construction, hence it receives null *mockProxy* reference.

If for some reason you don't want to use @InjectMocks, the only way is to construct your *Service* object within the test method body or within the @Before annotated setUp method.

Answer (score 3):

Write your test class as this, which will initialize `Service` with a mock of `ServiceProxy`:

```
class ServiceTest
{
@Mock
ServiceProxy mockProxy;

//This will inject the "ServiceProxy" mock into your "Service" instance.
@InjectMocks
Service service = new Service(mockProxy);

@Before
public void init() {
//This will initialize the annotated mocks 
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test() {
... 
}
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to use initMocks. If I don't use that and create the service instance in set up itself then just declaring the @Mock works. Why ?

Comment: `@Mock` define the mock objects. `@InjectMocks` defines where the mock objects need to be injected. Now you need some type of annotation processor to process the annotations present in this class so that `Mockito` can actually inject `@Mock` objects into `@InjectMocks`. And this part is played by `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: It's not working because mockProxy is null when passed to Service constructor.

Comment: can you update your question with the changes you made to your test class?