# How to mock an objects method call thats within a method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So here is the class and method I want to create a test for:

```
public class RequestController {    
private GetAllInter getAnalytics;//This is an interface

@RequestMapping(value ="",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllAnalytics(){
    log.debug("Processing request for all analytics");
    String result;
    try {
        result = getAnalytics.getAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "Could not retrieve full list of analytics";
        log.error(result,e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Specifically I want mock the getAnalytics.getAll() so it returns a String I already defined. Instead of the method doing its thing. This is my code:

```
public class RequestControllerTest extends Mockito{

private String allAnalyticsStr = "Hello";

@Test
public void testGetAllAnalytics(){
    GetAllInter getAll = mock(GetAllInter.class);
    when(getAll.getAll()).thenReturn("what");
    RequestController requestController = new RequestController();
    assert(requestController.getAllAnalytics().equals("Hello"));
}
```

And when I try to run the test this is the error im getting:

> 16:17:03.240 [main] DEBUG dar.RequestController - Processing requst for all analytics
>   16:17:03.248 [main] ERROR dar.RequestController - Could not retrieve full list of analytics
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at dar.RequestController.getAllAnalytics(RequestController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
>       at dar.RequestControllerTest.testGetAllAnalytics(RequestControllerTest.java:28) [test-classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
>   and
>
> java.lang.AssertionError
>       at dar.RequestControllerTest.testGetAllAnalytics(RequestControllerTest.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is there another way to do this? Is it because I am mocking an interface of the class and not the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace RequestController#getAnalytics field with mocked GetAllInter instance before executing test.

```
GetAllInter getAll = mock(GetAllInter.class);
when(getAll.getAll()).thenReturn("what");
```

That statement doesn't effect RequestController's getAnalytics instance behavior until you set it as RequestController's field.

I found similar question
[mockito - mocking an interface - throwing NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689061/mockito-mocking-an-interface-throwing-nullpointerexception)

The easiest way is provide setter for RequestController#getAllanalytics or provide RequestController constructor taking GetAllInter argument.

But using @InjectMocks would be nicer solution since you don't need to modify the RequestController class for testing.